# how to compare the date in xml row with today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one xml file which is retrieved using jquery in sharepoint. One of the row of the xml is like below.

```
<z:row ows_Title='Have dinner party with Host' ows_Due_x0020_Date='2012-05-10 00:00:00' ows_MetaInfo='1;#' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_ID='1' ows_UniqueId='1;#{2A8F277A-C95B-420C-89A9-3B979F95C8F4}' ows_owshiddenversion='3' ows_FSObjType='1;#0' ows_Created='2012-10-25 03:19:35' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2012-10-29 00:56:09' ows_FileRef='1;#personal/Inclusions/Lists/Events/1_.000' />
```

Now i want to retireve the "Due Date" column and compare with the today's date. For retrieving date there is no issue. But how to compare the both dates? For comparing the date with today I used like this.

```
    var k = new Date();
    var year = k.getYear();
    var month = k.getMonth();
    var day = k.getDate();
    var fulldate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day
```

But it is displaying only with date. In xml we are getting time also. I dont want to compare with time. I want to compare with only dates. How to achieve it? I want to put that whole process in the following function.

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() { 
          //here i want to compare that date column with present date

});
```

Finally i want, the date coming in the xml is less than the today's date or not?

Comment: What do you mean by _compare_? What do you want to compare between the two dates? Days in between? Months?...

Comment: I want to compare, date coming in xml is less than the today date or not.

Comment: You should use `.getFullYear()` anyways

Comment: `.getYear()` also giving the same result. Any way thanks for that suggestion. But issue not with this function.

Comment: I'm not sure it is giving the same result - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear . Anyways, I was just pointing it out, I wasn't saying that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function isPastDate( date ) {
  return (new Date( date )).getTime() < (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Comment: While comparing, date coming from the xml is giving as `NaN`

Comment: `date` must be a string. Make sure the date is in the expected format, for example `mm-dd-yyyy`. If you got your string from xml you can extract the values, create an array and join accordingly to create the expected format.

Comment: Yes.. the problem coming for the date format. It is in `YYYY-MM-DD` but we need `MM-DD-YYYY` format

Comment: Then you need to convert it to the right format using the method I explain above...

Comment: But while retrieving from xml i am using `$(this).attr("ows_Due_x0020")`. But this value giving as undefined. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ows_Due_x0020_Date`?

Comment: Yes Brother... I mistakenly typed that one.. Thanks. Now need to convert that into required format.

Comment: You can use an array to split the values and put them back together or a simple replacement with regex: `'2012-05-10'.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, '$2/$3/$1')`

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend Date.js library for all the comparison and formatting methods that can make a lot of date work greatly simplified

http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

finally the required comparison like below.

```
function compareDates(passdate)
    {   
        var splitdate = passdate.split(" ");
        var splitdate1 = splitdate[0].split("-");
        var newdate = splitdate1[1]+"-"+ splitdate1[2]+"-"+splitdate1[0];
        return ((Date.parse(newdate)) < (new Date()).getTime());
    }
```